# How to upload apk in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, file

I'm developing a back end to upload pdf file and apk file.
To upload pdf I use Multipart File

```
@PostMapping(value="secure/book/create", produces = "application/json")
    public Book create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("title") String title, @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam("language") String language,
            @RequestParam("price") BigDecimal price, @RequestParam("numberOfPages") int numberOfPages)  {
        logger.info("Creation of a  new book "+title);

    }
```

And works well.

To upload an apk, I develop this method :

```
@PostMapping(value="apk/create", produces = "application/json")
    public ApkFile create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)  {
        logger.info("Creation of a  new apk "+file.getName());
        return apkService.uploadApk(file);

    }
```

but I never entered inside my method.
What its wrong with the code to upload apk ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add an exception stacktrace that you get when you attempt to call an apk/create method

Comment: @MarkBramnik I didn't enter inside the methode. I don't have an exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I added the max size limitand the file is accepted.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```